# Cant connect or ping my router after changing it's ip address

Tags: ip

English is not my first language, sorry if I'm not well understood.

I'm trying to add another router for my house, so the WiFi range will be larger.
Now, my first router's IP is 192.168.1.1, and it works well. The second, which I want to make a second access point, has 10.0.0.138 as its address. I want to change it to 192.168.1.x, I've tried replacing x with 2 and 249, with and without being a DHCP server. When I change its IP, the web page disappears and I plug and unplug the Ethernet cable, the pc gets an IP address within the new subnet.
Yet, I cannot ping or connect to the web page of the router, not in the new address nor in the former one. When I connect it to the router that works it does not read it as a Ethernet connected device I don't know what to do, I'll be glad to get some help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The router may have a errors that prevent a changed IP address from fully working. However, if all you need is Wi-Fi, you don’t have to change the IP address at all. Not changing it will make accessing the web interface harder, you’ll manually have to change your computer’s IP address to do that. Other than that, there will be no problems.

Just leave the IP address as is and disable DHCP. Set up the Wi-Fi name and security as required. Connect the LAN port of the “new” router to any LAN port of the existing router, done.

Your existing router only lists devices that tried to reach the internet (and maybe Wi-Fi devices). Your “new” router will never access the internet and as such will never appear on this list.

If you lost all access to the “new” router, you can try to reset it. Its default configuration will surely work.

Comment: If the idea is to make a WiFi extender of this new router, then Daniel is right: just plug one end of an Ethernet cable in a LAN port on router 1 (which has access to the Internet), the other end in a LAN port on router 2, and the latter will de facto get connectivity. You'll have to choose an SSID for this extender, but it'll share bandwidth with router 1, so the more devices you'll connect to router 2 via WiFi, the slower the connection for devices connected to router 1. A good setup would be to disable WiFi on router 1, place router 2 where it's the most efficient, and use one access point.

Comment: Will it work even though they are not in the same subnet? And will another lan spot in my house work as a connection? And Most importantly, does that mean the router has a problem, and another one would work?

Comment: Yes. If you use a router as an access point, it is essentially a layer 2 device. IP not involved. Any wired network connection will do. // Yes, normally the settings a router presents are supposed to work. However, consumer router firmware quality is often very bad.

Comment: So I can't be home right now for some time due to the coronavirus, but my dad says he tried this with 3 more different routers and the same thing happened. I will check and confirm when I get home, but is it even possible for something like that to happen? Is it a provlem in the cable? CP's IP? what could it be?

Comment: The answer is simple and probably not satisfying: Human error is the most likely cause.